# AWS EC2 Instance status checks, I see that the “Instance reachability check” has failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have installed Rasa X and Rasa Open Source on EC2 using Docker Containers.

Initially it works fine and I am able to access the Rasa X UI and also able to run the bot on my website. But after sometime (24-36 hrs), the bot goes down.

In the AWS EC2 Instance status checks, I see that the “Instance reachability check” has failed.

Not sure what is going wrong. Neither am I able to pull out any relevant logs.

Can someone please help in figuring out this issue.

Comment: Why are you not able to pull out relevant logs? Can't you log in? When it happens, have you checked the metrics for CPU? You need to check system logs for `Out of memory` as well. Also, please check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-status-check-failure/ to troubleshoot.

Comment: When I try to login via SSH, I am shown a TimeOut Error. On checking the system logs, I don't see any `Out of memory` error.

There is a sudden spike in CPU Utilisation at 94% after which it falls down to 0 % which I assume is because the instance got shut down.

Comment: You can check `Actions->SystemSettings->Get System Log` to see what causes the instance to shutdown.